# How handle uneven partition in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

So i have a data frame which output 300 GB records into S3 .
All the data is partitioned in 2K partition.

```
.partitionBy("DataPartition", "PartitionYear", "PartitionStatement")
```

But the issue is some of the partition has very huge data (40GB) and some has only 10MB .

So if i re partition it again like `.repartition(100)` then it creates many files for even 10MB data size partition also and that leads to huge no of output files .
When i try to load all the output files and run my spark job then because of many small files my spark job becomes very slow .

What i am looking for is can we re partition only those data frames which has huge no of records .

Lest say i know for below partition`(Japan 1970 BAL)` the records will be huge so can we repartition that partition only ?

I did not found anything about this on internet .

I tried even this

```
dfMainOutputFinalWithoutNull.repartition($"DataPartition", $"PartitionYear", $"PartitionStatement")
      .write
      .partitionBy("DataPartition", "PartitionYear")
```

But this also did not turns out in good performance .

Please suggest something so that my output files no also not become every huge and my job also runs faster .

This is not working for me

```
 val rddFirst = sc.textFile(mainFileURL)
    val rdd = rddFirst.repartition(190)
```

Because when i try to split the file name i get error .

Comment: you should repartition equally in all executors. the way you are repartitioning is good before you perform series of aggregations . So before write process you should repartition as many as you have executors. lets say you have 16 executors running parallelly then you should do .repartition(16) and you should be good

Comment: @RameshMaharjan But if .repartition(16) then it will create 2K*16 total files would be 32K and then if load all this next time in spark Will it not create problem ?

Comment: reduce the repartition value then

Comment: @RameshMaharjan `rddFirst.repartition(190)` will it work ? ..I am getting one field from file name also

Comment: I don't know if that will get you the fastest time. You got to test it with different configurations . may be increase the executors or increasing and decreasing the memory and many more. I repeat again **you should repartition equally in all executors**